# Display term refference field in node

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have term refference in user fields. I would like to show under name of author's node that field.

I try this code:

```
<?php print $node_author->field_NAME[$node->language][0]['taxonomy_term']; ?>
```

But this won't work.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a term reference field in user profile and you want to display it into the node view.

By default, the profile fields are not included in the user information of the node object. You only have `$node->uid`. You would need to load it explicitly in [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7). There are two ways to make that data available to the template.

**1. Directly render to the template**

You can add the field data into the `$node->content[]` which are automatically rendered in the node.tpl.php. You can adjust the field order using `#weight`.

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL) {
    if($view_mode == 'full'){
        // Load all user fields of the node author
        $node_author = user_load($node->uid);
        // Get term name            
        $term_name = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'td')
                        ->fields('td', array('name'))
                        ->condition('td.tid', $node_author->field_taxonomy_term[$node->language][0]['tid'])
                        ->execute()
                        ->fetchField();
        // directly render to the template                          
        $node->content['field_taxonomy_term'] = array(     
            '#markup' => '<div>'.$term_name.'</div>', 
            '#weight' => -1,
        );
    }  
}
```

**2. Make the field available to the template and print it as you need**

You can make the field available to the [THEME_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) and `node.tpl.php` by adding the field to the `$node` object which is available in `hook_node_view()`. And then print it in the template file.

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL) {
    if($view_mode == 'full'){
        // Load all user fields of the node author
        $node_author = user_load($node->uid);
        // Get term name            
        $term_name = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'td')
                        ->fields('td', array('name'))
                        ->condition('td.tid', $node_author->field_taxonomy_term[$node->language][0]['tid'])
                        ->execute()
                        ->fetchField();

        // make it availabe to the template
        $node->field_taxonomy_term = $term_name;
    }  
}
```

Print it where you want in the template file, `node.tpl.php` in this case.

```
<?php print render($field_taxonomy_term); ?>
```

The field name `field_taxonomy_term` is your field name defined in your user fields.

Comment: Do i edit in module field_taxonomy_term to my field name? And do i edit this: $term_name ... Because when i add this code to my module, it wont work... Thank you very much!

Comment: My bad.. Working like a charm! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust some of the settings of a field on the 'manage fields' tab of the content type configuration.

To position or further manipulate the output of a particular field in the template, edit node.tpl.php and where you want your field to appear, add

```
if(!empty($content['field_term'])) {
  print render($content['field_term']);
}
```

(Or if your field isn't called 'field_term', whatever your field's name is.)

Comment: I think OP wants to display a field of user profile (author of the node) in the node view. Not a field of a content type.